# Markov chains transition identity proof

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Let $X = (X_{n})_{n \geq 0}$ a Markov chain proof that

$$\mathbb{P}(X_{n + 2} = j \mid X_{n} = i) = \sum_{l \in \mathcal{S}} \mathbb{P}(X_{n + 2} = j, X_{n + 1} = l \mid X_{n} = i)$$

Note: $\mathcal{S}$ denotes the state space.

Comment: Have you tried anything? And how do you interpret this equality?

Comment: Yes, I proved using the following relationship for Markov chains $\mathbb{P}(X_{n + 2} = j, X_{n + 1} = l \mid X_{n} = i) = \mathbb{P}(X_{n + 2} = j \mid X_{n} = i) P(X_{n + 1} = l \mid X_{n} = i)$ and taking sums over all $l \in \mathcal{S}$. I interpret this equality as the way to pass to random variable $n + 2$ is to go over all the intermediate states of the random variable $n + 1$.

Comment: The Markov property is not needed to prove this.

Comment: Yes, there is not need to use the Markov Property. I added my solution without using the Markov as an answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score -1):

**Simple Proof without using the Markov Property**:

Using the fact that $\Omega = \bigcup_{l \in \mathcal{S}} \{ X_{n + 1} = l\}$, this is a disjoint union, then

$$    \begin{align}
      \mathbb{P}(X_{n + 2} = j \mid X_{n} = i) &= \mathbb{P}(\{ X_{n + 2} = j \} \cap \Omega \mid X_{n} = i)  \\
      &= \mathbb{P}\left(\{ X_{n + 2} = j\} \cap \left[ \bigcup_{l \in \mathcal{S}} \{ X_{n + 1} = l\} \right] \mid X_{n} = i \right) \\
      &= \mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{l \in \mathcal{S}} \left[ \{ X_{n + 1} = l\} \cap \{ X_{n + 2} = j\}  \right] \mid X_{n} = i \right) \\
      &= \sum_{l \in \mathcal{S}} \mathbb{P}\left( \{ X_{n + 1} = l\} \cap \{ X_{n + 2} = j\}  \mid X_{n} = i \right) \\
      &= \sum_{l \in \mathcal{S}} \mathbb{P}\left(X_{n + 1} = l,X_{n + 2} = j \mid X_{n} = i \right)
    \end{align}
$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be: $P(X_{n+2}=j,X_{n+1}=l|X_n=i)=P(X_{n+2}=j|X_{n+1}=l)P(X_{n+1}=l|X_n=i)$ in the first equality?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'm checking my counts.

Comment: It's possible to proof that $\mathbb{P}(X_{n + 2} = j \mid X_{n} = i) P(X_{n + 1} = l \mid X_{n} = i) = \mathbb{P}(X_{n + 2} = j \mid X_{n + 1} = l) \mathbb{P}(X_{n + 1} = l \mid X_{n} = i)$.

Comment: The first identity in this answer is still bogus.